# MS Access - background image prints on every other page

Tags: ms-access

I have a paper form that I scanned in and created a .bmp file.  I put that file into the Picture property and set the Picture Type to Embedded.  I then laid my data fields on top of the appropriate areas on the report.

When I go to print preview, every page has the data in the proper place, but the image shows up on every other page, so that pages 2,4,6 etc. only have the data fields.  How do I get the image to print on every page?

Comment: Have you set the "PicturePages" property to "All Pages"?

Comment: "All Pages" is the default. Other options are "First Page" and "No Pages". So something else must be going on. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. I cannot replicate issue. I did something similar but I used a jpg in an Image control, not a background image of the report.